# Measuring Android network performance from inside an app

Tags: android, networking

Is it possible to measure Android network performance from inside an app?
Or from the Android shell?

I am trying to measure network performance of my app that uses both the Android HTTP APIs and a WebView. I would like to see bits per second going to different IP addresses.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at the ARO tool provided by AT&T. It is free to use and open source. It will let you analyze your network activity, battery consumption and CPU usage.
The analysis options are detailed, with individual addresses and IP addresses listed as well as information on where the same data is being fetched twice.
http://developer.att.com/aro

Comment: Thanks! Haven't heard of this before.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with mobify but warning, it requires much setup: http://www.akamai.com/html/about/press/releases/2012/press_032012.html